# Overhead of creating new SqlConnection in c#

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlconnection

A while back I wrote an ORM layer for my .net app where all database rows are represented by a subclass of `DatabaseRecord`. There are a number of methods like `Load()`, `Save()` etc. In my initial implementation I created a connection to the DB in the constructor of `DatabaseRecord` e.g.

```
connection = new SqlConnection(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionName"].ConnectionString
);
```

I then call `Open()` and `Close()` on that SqlConnection at the beginning and end of my methods which access the database. This seemed to me (as someone who was familiar with programming but new to c# and .net) to be the most efficient way to do things - have one connection and open/ close it where necessary within the class.

I've just been doing some reading though and it appears that this pattern is recommended in a number of places:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...)) {
    connection.Open();
    // Stuff with the connection
    connection.Close();
}
```

I can see why it's desirable - the connection is automatically `Dispose()`d even if the stuff you do in the middle causes an uncaught exception. I was just wondering what the overhead is for calling `new SqlConnection()` potentially many times like this.

Connection Pooling is on so I imagine the overhead is minimal and the second approach should be best practice but I just wanted to make sure my assumptions are right.

Comment: Thanks for all the amazingly quick answers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is best practice. The `using` makes your call to Close() exception-safe.

And the overhead of creating a (any) object is indeed minimal, and smallest for short-lived objects (that stay in GC generation 0).

Note that you don't have to call Close() at the end of the using-block anymore, it is automatically done for you (Dispose==Close).

Comment: How minimal? Are there any benchmarks anywhere that show how much performance is lost from opening and closing connections? Is there a network handshake that goes on when the Open method is called?

Comment: Actually, I think this article answers my question perfectly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling

Comment: If this article is correct, connection pooling should explicitly handle handshaking etc. and make sure that no unnecessary handshaking goes on.

Answer (score 1):

This is partially a matter of taste. As long as you employ connection pooling the overhead of creating a new (recycling a pooled connection) will be minimal, so generally the recommended pattern is to create new connection objects as needed.

If you run several commands immediately after each other then I see no reason to create new connections for each of them, but you should avoid holding on to open connections for a long time.

Also, you should note that the `Dispose` method will close the connection for you. So there is no need to call both `Close` and `Dispose`. Since the `using` clause will call dispose when it ends there is normally no need to call `Close`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're unsure about the cost of opening/closing connection, have the `SqlConnection` a member variable of your class, but make the class `IDisposable` and dispose of the SqlConnection when the class is disposed

Comment: Actually, thinking about it more I think that this could be the more efficient approach. I've fleshed out your suggestion a bit in another question - it would be great if you could let me know if I understood right:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020576/creating-an-idisposable-class-in-c-which-cleans-up-an-sqlconnection-when-finishe